# Python, for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
def get_asset_info(asset_list):

    import datetime

    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    day = today.strftime("%d")

    for i in range( len( asset_list )):
        raw_info = get_OHLC( asset_list[i], 15, get_server_time() )

        info = raw_info['result'][asset_list[i]]
        head = "time,open,high,low,close,vwap,volume,count"

        formatted_info = ""

        for i in range(len(info[0])):
            formatted_info = formatted_info + info[0][i] + ","

        file = open(asset_list[i]+"_"+day, "a")
        file.write(head + "\n")
        file.write(formatted_info)
        file.close()
```

It is supposed to get some values, convert it into a string and write it to a file, dynamically generated.
It's not working like this and all the values are put in the same file.

If I change the last part of the code like the following, the files are generated:

```
    formatted_info = str(info[0][0]) + "," + str(info[0][1]) + "," + str(info[0][2]) + "," + str(info[0][3]) + "," + str(info[0][4]) + "," + str(info[0][5]) + "," + str(info[0][6]) + "," + str(info[0][7])

    file = open(asset_list[i]+"_"+day, "a")
    file.write(head + "\n")
    file.write(formatted_info)
    file.close()
```

So the problem, as I can see, is in the for loop I create to generate my string, but there's no sense since the code that generates the file is not in the same loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: indent your file writing block, otherwise its only writing out the last instance of `formatted_info`

Comment: You're using the same variable `i` for your inner loop and your outer loop. Use a different variable.

Comment: It is possible to get rid of the inner loop altogether, just use this: `formatted_info = ",".join(info[0]) + ","`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in range( len( asset_list )):
    ...
    for i in range(len(info[0])):
        ...
    # now what do you think i is now?
    file = open(asset_list[i]+"_"+day, "a")
```

Changing second `i` to `j` should do the trick:

```
for i in range( len( asset_list )):
    ...
    for j in range(len(info[0])):
        formatted_info = formatted_info + info[0][j] + ","

    file = open(asset_list[i]+"_"+day, "a")
```

or even better:

```
for i in range( len( asset_list )):
    ...
    for piece in info[0]:
        formatted_info = formatted_info + str(piece) + ","

    file = open(asset_list[i]+"_"+day, "a")
```

or finally better:

```
for i in range( len( asset_list )):
    ...
    formatted_info = ','.join(str(obj) for obj in info[0]) + ','
    file = open(asset_list[i]+"_"+day, "a")
```

Comment: First code is ok, 
second one must be used like this to work:
    for piece in info[0]:
        formatted_info = formatted_info + str(piece) + ","
Third one, a disaster.
Lots of thank

Comment: @Frey Well, there's no `str` in your original code which suggests that those arrays contain strings. Anyway I've updated the answer.

Comment: That's an elegant way of doing the thing.
Just forgot to modify the code when I copied it